# Delete any rows with NA values and any other row with the same subject id

Tags: r

How to delete all rows with any `NA` values in a DataFrame, and also delete all other rows with the same `subjectid` as the rows deleted?

Comment: Smells like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), how did you get the data, are they a result of an unsuccessful `merge` (or join or whatsoever)?

Answer (score 0):

In base R you can simply subset based on those IDs with an NA in the desired column (ie, in the below example, we want to exclude IDs 1 and 2):

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5),
                 val = c(2,NA,NA,NA,1,2,3,4,5,6))

df[!df$id %in% unique(df[is.na(df$val), "id"]),]

#   id val
#5   3   1
#6   3   2
#7   4   3
#8   4   4
#9   5   5
#10  5   6
```

If you want to look for `NA`s across columns for all rows and exclude IDs with an NA anywhere (here we want to exclude IDs 1, 2, and 3):

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5),
                 val = c(2,NA,NA,NA,1,2,3,4,5,6),
                 val2 = c(1,2,3,4,NA,NA,7,8,9,10))


df[!df$id %in% unique(df[apply(df, 1, function(x) any(is.na(x))), "id"]),]

#   id val val2
#7   4   3    7
#8   4   4    8
#9   5   5    9
#10  5   6   10
```

Comment: Sure, this works if we had one column other than `id`, what if we had several columns?

Comment: Thank you for trying! I tried it but it is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it, if anyone is interested here is the code:

```
# Step 1: Get unique subjectid of rows with NA values
removed_subjectid <- unique(df$subjectid[apply(df, 1, function(x) any(is.na(x)))])

# Step 2: Remove rows with subjectid from the vector in Step 1
df <- df[!(df$subjectid %in% removed_subjectid), ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's the answer of your question

```
library(dplyr)

test_data <- data.frame(subjectid = c("1", "2", "3", "3", "4", "5", "6", "8"), 
                        Val = c(NA, 1, 135, 56, NA, NA, 2, 3))

dupl_subjectid <- test_data |> 
  group_by(subjectid) |> 
  filter(n() > 1) |> 
  distinct(subjectid) |> 
  pull()

filtered_test_data <- test_data |> 
  filter(!is.na(Val) & !subjectid %in% dupl_subjectid   )
```